# Select Value Match - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

Can you advise if it is possible, to select a count for numerous substrings in a query

so if I have a message field which contains for example, text messages and I could do

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM MESSAGES 
WHERE MESSAGE_BODY LIKE '%hello%'
```

but what I want to do is more:

```
SELECT STRING, COUNT(1) 
FROM MESSAGES 
WHERE MESSAGE_BODY IN (list of strings with wild card)
```

is this possible?

to break down example:

ID | Message_Body
1 | Hello, How Are You?
2 | Hi, Great Thanks
3 | Hello, How is things?
4 | Ciao

Output wanted:

hello , 2 
ciao, 1

SELECT (input strings), COUNT(1)
FROM TABLE
WHERE (input strings) IN ('%hello%','%ciao%')

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT t.string,
       CASE WHEN t.MESSAGE_BODY LIKE '%laptop%' then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.MESSAGE_BODY LIKE '%one%' then 1 else 0 END +
       CASE WHEN t.MESSAGE_BODY LIKE '%two%' then 1 else 0 END as count_col
FROM YourTable t
```

If you just want multiple `LIKE` comaparison, use `REGEXP_LIKE()` :

```
SELECT STRING, COUNT(1) 
FROM MESSAGES
where regexp_like(MESSAGE_BODY, 'one|two|laptop')
```

**EDIT:** You can use a derived table containing all strings you are intrested on and left join to the original table for count:

```
SELECT t.wrd,COUNT(s.id) as cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 'hello' as wrd FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ciao' as wrd FROM DUAL) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN messages s
 ON(s.message_body LIKE '%' || t.wrd || '%')
GROUP BY t.wrd
```

Comment: Where does `STRING` come from?

Comment: I don't know, assumed he knows what he is doing (he used it in his select)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info - is there a way so that in the "select" the string value is the strings I enter in the where clause and it counts each occurence?

Comment: First you have to help me understand you better. Post data sample and expected output because I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the post to try and be a bit more clear:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is with looking for whole words:

```
  SELECT a.word, COUNT (message.message_body)
    FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('hello,ciao', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) word
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('hello,ciao', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN MESSAGES ON REGEXP_INSTR (MESSAGE_BODY, '(^|\s)' || a.word || '(\s|$)', 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0
GROUP BY a.word
```